# Center image and keep it at bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with keeping an image at the bottom of my sidebar.  When I'm able to center it, it wants to join the higher-up links and won't come down, and when I force it to the bottom, I can't get it to center without dangerous margin hacks.

```
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 25%;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
 }

  .sidebar li:nth-of-type(1) {
        padding-top: 10%;
      }


.sidebar li {
  color: #8B2500;
  margin-top: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
  #add {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
```

The html :

```
<nav class="sidebar"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"></img>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li> <a href="docs.html"> Providers </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Quality </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
            </ul>
            <img id="add" src="images/phoner.png"></img>
        </nav>
```

The image in question is the #add.  Position: absolute; brings it to the bottom as desired, but floats it left, and position: relative; brings it center as desired, but pulls it from the bottom.  Any input appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are nearly there, the trick in positiong element at the center, when you are using position: absolute is by adding a left,top,right,bottom a 50% and substract the half of the size of the element you want to center. 
In your case you just need to

**CSS**

```
#add {
    display: block; // remove
    margin: 0 auto; // remove
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%; //added
    margin-left: -40px; //added
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
```

see my sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owguy80q/)

Answer (score 1):

try this it should work

```html
<nav class="sidebar"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"></img>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li> <a href="docs.html"> Providers </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Quality </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <img id="add" src="images/phoner.png"></img>
        </nav>
```

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 25%;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
 }

  .sidebar li:nth-of-type(1) {
        padding-top: 10%;
      }


.sidebar li {
  color: #8B2500;
  margin-top: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
  #add {
     bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }
.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a container element? That would prevent you from needing explicit sizing or margins.

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 80vh;
  max-width: 25%;
  position: fixed;
  background: pink;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
}
.stuck-centered {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;

}
#add {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="stuck-centered">
    <img id="add" src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></img>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**[Full demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kprq5a9m/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
.COOLelement{ 
    position:fixed; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    bottom:0;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem raised by the asker, it's better to include some explanation alongside the code to help future readers.

Comment: Well, it's too late now.

Comment: Thumbs up for you anyway Mr. Christmas